# Editing ADPropertyValueCollection (IList)

Tags: powershell

From AD, I obtained a variable with `ADPropertyValueCollection` type with `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate` inside.

Looks like this:

```
> $test
Handle      Issuer      Subject
1234        CA1         CN=user1
2345        CA2         CN=user2
3456        CA3         CN=user3
```

I want to remove one position from the list, and add another one. Unfortunately I have no idea on how to do it - I found that this is an `IList`, which supports `Remove` method, but it seems I don't know how to use it.

I thought that maybe PS supports something like
`$test[Handle = 1234]`, but apparently it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoke [`IList.Remove()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.remove) by passing the object that you want removed to it as an argument, so you could do something like:

```
$objectToRemove = $test |Where-Object Handle -eq 1234 |Select-Object -First 1
$test.Remove($objectToRemove)
```